# Putting a smaller 3D matrix into a bigger 3D matrix (3D sub2ind)

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to put a smaller 3D matrix into a bigger 3D matrix. Explaining with an example:

Suppose I have the following 3D matrices:

```
%A is the big matrix
A(:,:,1)=[ 0.3545    0.8865    0.2177
           0.9713    0.4547    0.1257
           0.3464    0.4134    0.3089];

A(:,:,2)=[  0.7261    0.0098    0.7710
            0.7829    0.8432    0.0427
            0.6938    0.9223    0.3782];

A(:,:,3) = [0.7043    0.2691    0.6237
            0.7295    0.6730    0.2364
            0.2243    0.4775    0.1771];

%B is the small matrix
B(:,:,1) = [0.3909    0.5013 
            0.0546    0.4317];


B(:,:,2) =[0.4857    0.1375 
           0.8944    0.3900];

B(:,:,3) =[0.7136    0.3433
           0.6183    0.9360];
```

Now to put B in A such that: use  first dimension: [1 3], second dimension  [2 3] and do this for [1,2,3] pages of A. For the given matrix, putting these values will result in:

```
NewA(:,:,1) = [ 0.3545    0.3909    0.5013     % putting the value of %B(1,:,1)
                0.9713    0.4547    0.1257
                0.3464    0.0546    0.4317;   % putting the value of %B(2,:,1)


NewA(:,:,2)=[  0.7261    0.4857    0.1375      % putting the value of %B(1,:,2)
               0.7829    0.8432    0.0427
               0.6938    0.8944    0.3900];    % putting the value of %B(2,:,2)


NewA(:,:,3) = [0.7043    0.7136    0.3433      % putting the value of %B(1,:,3)
               0.7295    0.6730    0.2364
               0.2243    0.6183    0.9360];    % putting the value of %B(2,:,3)
```

I won't necessarily have square matrices as 3D pages and the size of `A` to put `B` in can vary as well. But the matrices will always be 3D. Above is just a small example. What I actually have is dimensions as big as A -> [500,500,5] and B as -> [350,350,4].

This is what `sub2ind` do for 2D matrices but I am not yet able to manipulate into use for 3D matrices.

Something like:

```
NewA = A;  
NewA(sub2ind(size(A), [1 3], [2 3], [1 2 3])) = B;
```

but it gives:

```
Error using sub2ind (line 69)
The subscript vectors must all be of the same size.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to see what you're doing if you used more distinct values in your examples. Matching to 4 decimal places is a bit tedious. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "first dimension: [1 3], second dimension [2 3]", etc. The values you show for `B(2,:,1)` and `B(2,:,2)` don't match your example `B`.

Comment: If I ignore the values in your `NewA` matrix and just look at the comments, you might be looking for `NewA = A; NewA([1,3], [2,3], :) = B;`. Can you give us an example of the subscript ranges you want to use for the larger matrix?

Comment: Thanks @beaker! I did not realise that I had made typos :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `sub2ind`, just assign directly:

```
newA(1,2:3,:)=B(1,:,:)
```

---

If you want to use `sub2ind`, you need to specify each of the 3 dimensions, for each of the elements you want to replace:

```
dim1A=[1 1 1 1 1 1];  % always first row
dim2A=[2 3 2 3 2 3];  % second and third column, for each slice
dim3A=[1 1 2 2 3 3];  % two elements from each slice

newA(sub2ind(size(A),dim1A,dim2A,dim3A))=B(1,:,:)

newA(:,:,1) =

    0.3545    0.3909    0.5013
    0.9713    0.4547    0.1257
    0.3464    0.4134    0.3089


newA(:,:,2) =

    0.7261    0.4857    0.1375
    0.7829    0.8432    0.0427
    0.6938    0.9223    0.3782


newA(:,:,3) =

    0.7043    0.7136    0.3433
    0.7295    0.6730    0.2364
    0.2243    0.4775    0.1771
```

Comment: How would I apply the first method for  say 500*500*5 dimensions? I know that way sir but I don't understand the first method without hardcoding or loops. btw I wrote first dimension to be [1 3] in my question but I'll take that as understood/typo in your answer. Regarding the second method, I think I can do that with repmat. I'll try that

Comment: Specify what exactly you want that will happen in the case of 500X500. That is 2D? Both A and B are 500 x 500? You need to clarify it a little better

Comment: What do you not understand, I'll try to rephrase that?

Comment: A and B are both 500X500? Are they 2D? Which elements exactly you want to replace from that 500x500 matrix?

Comment: 500*500*5 is a 3D matrix. Try entering `size(rand(500,500,5))` in your command window. Do you mean whether each page of that matrix is 2D? then yes. it is. I want to replace [1 3]  rows and [2 3] columns of [1 2 3] page of A with B in the example in my question

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see the "*5" at first. I know how that matrix looks like. So, A and B are both with these dimensions? You want to replace two element from each slice? which two? those in the end of first row? of A and of B?

Comment: they can be of any 3D dimensions but B will always have smaller dimensions and can always be put in A.  Not two elements, Sir. Number of elements depend on number of element of B since B is always smaller than A. I also checked your second method. It doesn't give the output I specified in the question

Comment: For the second option, I added the full results- as in the example in the question

Comment: For the bigger matrix, I just try to help you, so let's specify it... so B is always smaller or equal to A (are they squered in manner of 1st and 2nd dimensions?). You want to replace just the first row? All first row of B to the end of first row of A, for each of the slices?

Comment: And both of them has 5 slices at 3rd dimension?

Comment: Sir please take a look at the question again . I don't understand what you're asking that I already have not specified. There can be any rows just like you input in sub2ind for 2D.

Comment: I saw only the real dimensions you added. Can't be more specific than all my questions till now. Sorry.

Comment: The only idea I can guess from what you wrote is according to my first method in the answer, you can try: `newA(1,151:500,1:4)=B(1,:,:)`