# Mixing 3D arrays into a bigger 3D array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing, vectorization

I wish to fill a N x M x W matrix ‘S’ with the data from matrices ‘P’ and ‘Q’. They are defined below and illustrated in the attached image. Also, we know for sure that n_1 + n_2 = N, m < M, so all the data may fit in the ‘S’ matrix.

```
S = zeros(M,N,W);
P = rand(m,n_1,W);
Q = rand(m,n_2,W);
```

I wish to combine ‘P’ and ‘Q’ in a manner specified by 3 other matrices, ‘Line_num’, ‘P_col’ and ‘Q_col’, described below and in the middle part of the attached image.

```
P_col = randperm(N); P_col = P_col(1:n_1);          % 1 x n_1 matrix
Q_col = setxor(P_col, 1:1:N);           % 1 x n_2 matrix
```

Line_num is a matrix composed of W vectors of the form aa:1:bb, where bb-aa = m and aa is chosen at random for each vector.

The important thing is that in this case the data along the 3rd dimension in all these matrixes represent W different test cases, with the data being different and not to be mixed between each other.

To fill ‘S’ one may proceed in two logical steps (although if it can be done in one I shall be glad)

1. combine Q and P into an intermediate matrix Y of shape m x N x W by
   interweaving their columns. The columns specified in ‘Q_col’ are
   taken from Q (using the vector index) and put in the matrix Y (using
   the vector value). The same goes for P.
2. For each of the W vectors composing Line_num and arrays composing S,
   use the values in the vector Line_num to spread out Y to the
   corresponding rows in S, meanwhile maintaining their top to bottom
   order.

I wish to achieve this without for-loops as I am looking to ‘vectorize’ my code and thus improve its running speed.

I have had a look at [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/367188-how-to-filter-an-n-d-array-with-matrix-indexing) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826642/putting-a-smaller-3d-matrix-into-a-bigger-3d-matrix-3d-sub2ind) post, which are similar to what I desire. However they are simpler as the numbers to be extracted are constant. Maybe something similar would be appropriate?

Thank you for your help :)

[Link to the image aforementioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYrgc.png)

---

EDIT: here is an example code with a for-loop of what I want (my problem is that I want to get rid of the loop)

```
W = 4;
N = 10; n_1 = 4; n_2 = 6;
M = 20; m = 5;

P_col = [1,3,5,8];                      % 1 x n_1 matrix
Q_col = setxor(P_col, 1:1:N);           % 1 x n_2 matrix

line_num(:,:,1) = [1,5,10,15,18]; 
line_num(:,:,2) = [2,3,8,11,12]; 
line_num(:,:,3) = [4,7,8,14,19]; 
line_num(:,:,4) = [2,6,13,15,16]; 

S = zeros(M,N,W);
P = rand(m,n_1,W);
Q = rand(m,n_2,W);

for w=1:W
    line_num_I = line_num(:,:,w);
    S(line_num_I,Q_col,w) = Q(:,:,w);
    S(line_num_I,P_col,w) = P(:,:,w);
end
```

Comment: Please provide your tried for-loop. Sometime code explains the problem more better than image.

Comment: Consider that `P_col =randi(N,1,n_1);` creates repeated random numbers.

Comment: Yes I have just realized that. Thanks for pointing it out. Also, I added example code as you suggested.

Comment: the main problem is `line_num_I = line_num(:,:,w)` because it changes from a value of w to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution. I'm not sure if it is more efficient than loop version specially when the size of data is large.

```
 S (    reshape(line_num,[],1,W)       ...
        + ([Q_col-1 P_col-1]) * M      ...
        + (reshape(0:W-1,1,1,[]))*M*N  ...
   )                                   ...
   =                                   ...
   [reshape(Q,[],W);reshape(P,[],W)];
```

Here implicit expansion is used to convert subscripts to indices. Equivalently [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) can be used to compute linear indices:

```
S (                                     ...
    bsxfun(@plus,                       ...
        reshape(line_num,[],1,W),       ...
        bsxfun (@plus,                  ...
            ([Q_col-1 P_col-1]) * M,    ...
            (reshape(0:W-1,1,1,[]))*M*N ...
        )                               ...
    )                                   ...
  )                                     ...
  =                                     ...
  [reshape(Q,[],W);reshape(P,[],W)];
```

*[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51421742/6579744) You can find how to convert 3D index to lindex.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems great. However, it doesn't seem to give the exact same solution as the two other methods. Do you think it could be because `reshape(line_num,[],1,W)  + ([Q_col-1 P_col-1]) * M + (reshape(0:W-1,1,1,[]))*M*N` is a 3D matrix ?

Comment: No the solutions are exactly the same, you can test it [online](http://rextester.com/LVKBG87776). Please see the last line : `isequal(S,SS)`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had forgotten to add line `SS = zeros(M,N,W);`

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finding the answer. For those of you that it may interest, the above for-loop may be replaced by

```
% 1. Combine columns
mixed_col = zeros(m,N,W);
mixed_col(:,Q_col,:) = Q(:,:,:);
mixed_col(:,P_col,:) = P(:,:,:);
mixed_col = permute(mixed_col,[2,1,3]); % turn 3D matrix into 2D [1]
mixed_col = reshape(mixed_col,N,[],1)';

% 2. Combine lines
S = reshape(S,M*w,N,1); % turn 3D matrix into 2D [2]
line_num_v = permute(line_num + reshape((0:1:(W-1)).*M,1,1,W),[2,1,3]); % turn 3D matrix into 2D [3]
line_num_v = reshape(line_num_v,[],1,1);
S(line_num_v,:) = mixed_col(:,:); % combine using three 2D matrices
S = permute(reshape(S',N,M,W),[2,1,3]);
```

This involves lots of reshaping but I don't have a simpler answer.
Thanks again for your help.